# Light and snell law

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, refraction, geometric-optics

Why does light passing from one medium to another through normal doesn't  bend ? not mathmatical but theoritical explanation of a phenomenon required.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  Do you mean at normal incidence?

Comment: Which direction would you expect it to bend toward?

Answer (score 1):

Fermat's principle states that light gets from $A$ to $B$ in the minimum possible time, given how quickly it can move at any given intermediate speed $C$. I'll leave it to you to prove this implies Snell's law, or to find a proof of that implication elsewhere. But why is Fermat's principle right in the first place? We can restate it as a stationary action principle, as the time taken is $\int ds/v=\int nds/c$; minimising this integral can be interpreted as a geodesic in general relativity, but that's probably overkill.

Comment: Only in isotropic media.

Answer (score 1):

Another explanation, further to [J.G.'s answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/398332/26076), is simply "owing of symmetry". The answer has to be invariant if we rotate our co-ordianates about the normal, which comes to mean that the only transmission direction possible is along the normal.

In the absence of anisotropy, one asks the rhetorical question - which plane away from the normal would the transmitted light bend in? How would it know which way to bend if it didn't follow the normal?

If, however, the materials concerned are anisotropic, then it is an altogether different matter. The usual form of Snell's law is not fulfilled for anisotropic materials and it can well be the case that the least time path is indeed one where the light bends away from the normal. In this case, the answer to our rhetorical question is, "it is the anisotropy that chooses the direction".

Comment: @J.G. No, clearly not. Once you have a well defined plane of incidence, defined by an off-normal incident ray, the only information symmetry arguments can get you is that the ray must stay within the plane of incidence. I only gave the answer because (1) it shows that the answer is no even if we don't know any optics if the materials are isotropic and (2) it leads into the interesting observation that anisotropic materials behave very differently.

Answer (score 1):

The change in the direction of propagation is because two points of a wavefront do not propagate at the same velocity, as one is in medium 1 while the other is in medium 2.

[image]

You can see from the figure that, because point A propagates in a medium of higher index (thus slower speed), it will cover less distance in that medium than point B, which propagates in a medium with lower index (thus faster speed).  The result is that the direction of propagation, which is perpendicular to the wavefront, changes.

Of course at normal incidence, both points A and B - which are now parallel to the interface - will enter the denser medium a the same time and so will always cover the same distance in a given amount of time, i.e. they always remain parallel because they are always in the same medium.  This can *only* happen if A and B are parallel to the interface, so that the direction of propagation is normal to the interface.  Therefore, since A and B remain parallel to the interface, there will be no change in the direction of propagation, which remains normal to the interface.

Answer (score 1):

In a birefringent crystal, this is not really true. The ordinary ray obeys Snell's law, but the extraordinary ray does not. At normal incidence, the extraordinary ray will continue at an angle with the normal.

The difference is due to polarization. When the crystal is not cubic, the refractive index depends on the direction of the electric field vector. For example in calcite, all planar CO$_3^{2-}$ ions have their normal in the same direction.

Huygens already explained what was going on. When the speed of propagation of the light is not the same in all directions, the wavefronts are not spherical. In a birefringent crystal, the wavefronts are ellipsoids. The tangent to these ellipsoids is then a wavefront, that does not only depend on the angle of incidence but also on the optical axis of the crystal.

[image]